# Evaluate $\int \frac{\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate: $$  \space \space \int \frac{\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}\,dx $$

Please give proper directions/hints to evaluate this.

Comment: Hollie Mollie! This is a **very** different-looking function from the one we had before...have you made up your mind already?!

Comment: no, and sorry! I was just able to solve it while i posted it :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply let $t = \arcsin(\sqrt{x})$. Then $dt = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x} \cdot \sqrt{x}} dx$. So we end up wanting to deal with

$$\int 2t \sin t \ dt$$

Now do integration by parts with $u = t, dv = \sin t \ dt$.

Answer (score 1):

We pose $x=\cos^2\theta$ and we have
$$ I= \int \frac{\sin^{-1}\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=-2\int\theta\cos\theta d\theta, $$
and by integration by parts we have
$$I=-2\theta\sin\theta-2\cos\theta+C,$$
Finally we return to the  variable $x$ to find
$$I=-2\sqrt{x}-2\arcsin(\sqrt{x})\sqrt{1-x}+C.$$